# Calculate new Date() as seconds since midnight, January 1, 1970 UTC

Tags: javascript, google-maps, date-conversion

I am attempting to use the Google Maps [timezone API](https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/timezone/intro#RequiredParam) to get the datetime for a specific location (e.g. New York).

According to the API documentation:

> Required Parameters:
>
> `timestamp` specifies the desired time as seconds since midnight, January 1, 1970 UTC.

The issue I am having is calculating the difference in seconds from two `Date()` objects:

```
let currentDate = new Date();                   // local user time 
let epochDate = new Date('January 1, 1970');    // epoch date

// calculate seconds since (currentDate - epochDate)
```

Comment: `let epochDate = 0;` -- that's what an epoch *is*.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Use the `getTime()` function on a `Date` instance:

```
let secondsSinceEpoch = new Date().getTime() / 1000;
```

No need to set Epoch (January 1, 1970), all dates are relative to that date.